# 'MongoNetworkError' 'TransientTransactionError' ] unable to run the code

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am using a Windows 10 machine to run my javascript program. This is a new system and I have installed mongodb.

However, when I run my code using the command, node app.js , I am getting the following error:

```
{ MongoNetworkError: connect ETIMEDOUT 10.237.141.117:27011
    at Socket.err (C:\Users\Desktop\project\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connect.js:287:16)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

I am pretty sure the code has no issues as it is running well on other machines.

Answer (score 0):

In my case TransientTransactionError basically meant "connection to MongoDB server timed out/refused". So it was not an issue on a server itself, but inability to reach the server.

Rather confusing name for this kind of error.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when attempting to save a document. And I was able to fix it by changing a type in my Schema : `Schema.Types.Decimal128` was changed to `Number` for my situation.

It seems it was just a problem of unsuported type for my mongoDB version. But I had this generic error... It took me a lot of tries to sort this out.